# How to make validation on array for accounting debit and credit

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net, arrays

When looping, I want to do a validation for the debit and credit amount. When user enter at the debit column, the entry type will be '10' and when user enter at the credit column, the entry type will be '20', however user should not able to enter amount on debit and credit on same row. and at the end if the debit side and credit side amount are not tally, it will not be able to pass the data to ajax. I not sure how to do the validation on the array. Anyone has idea or any other suggestion that be more suitable for my case?

Beside, how can I add sequence number to the dynamical row and insert in array so that it can be save into database?
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L9z3g2w1/1/)

```
Example input:
|Description|Debit|Credit|
| Item A    | 500 |      | // scenario 1
| Supplier  |     |  500 |
| Item B    | 300 |      | //scenario 2
| Item C    | 300 |      | 
| Supplier  |     |  600 |
| Total     | 1100| 1100 |
```

Because for accounting they might input 1 debit 1 credit or 2 debit 1 credit but the amount for both side will be tally. So I make a scenario 1 and scenario 2.

Below is my coding, Im not sure how to make the validation for this. Please check my code

```
                <table id="example-input" class="table table-bordered text-nowrap">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th class="wd-5p"></th>
                      <th class=" wd-20p">Description</th>
                      <th class="wd-10p tx-right">Debit</th>
                      <th class="wd-10p tx-right">Credit</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody class="acc_table">
                    <tr class="acc-row">
                      <td>
                        <a id="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">Delete</i></a></td>
                      <td>
                        <input class="form-control tx-right row-accDesc" type="text"></td>
                      <td>
                        <input class="form-control tx-right row-dr" type="text" value="0"></td>
                      <td>
                        <input class="form-control tx-right row-cr" type="text" value="0"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                  <tfoot>
                    <tr id="hiderow">
                      <td colspan="6" class="tx-center tx-15"><b><a id="addrow" href="javascript:;" title="Add a row"><i class="fe fe-plus-circle"></i>Add a Row</a></b></td>
                      <br>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="valign-middle"></td>
                      <td class="tx-right">Total</td>
                      <td class="tx-right">
                        <input class="form-control tx-right" type="text" placeholder="0.00" id="debit" disabled></td>
                      <td class="tx-right">
                        <input class="form-control tx-right" type="text" placeholder="0.00" id="credit" disabled></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tfoot>
                </table>

<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                AddAccount();

                $('#addrow').click(function () {
                    addRow();
                });

            });

            $(document).on('click', '.delete-row', function () {
                $(this).parents('.acc-row').remove();
            });

            $(document).on('keyup', '.row-dr, .row-cr', function (e) {

                var dr = 0;
                cr = 0;
                total_cr = 0,
                total_dr = 0;

                var $row = $(this).closest("tr"); //this is the closest common root of the input elements
                dr += parseFloat($row.find('input.row-dr').val());
                cr += parseFloat($row.find('input.row-cr').val());

                //loop
                $(".acc-row").each(function () {
                    total_dr += $(this).find(".row-dr").val() != "" ? parseFloat($(this).find(".row-dr").val()) : 0
                    total_cr += $(this).find(".row-cr").val() != "" ? parseFloat($(this).find(".row-cr").val()) : 0
                })

                //add result to inputs
                $("#debit").val(total_dr.toFixed(2))
                $("#credit").val(total_cr.toFixed(2))

            });

            function addRow() {
                var addRows =
                    '<tr class="acc-row">' +
                    '<td><a class="delete-row" href="javascript:; ">Delete</i></a></td>' +
                    '<td><input class="form-control tx-right row-accDesc" type="text"></td>' +
                    '<td><input class="form-control tx-right row-dr" type="text"></td>' +
                    '<td><input class="form-control tx-right row-cr" type="text"></td>' +
                    '</tr>'
                $(".acc_table").append(addRows);
            }


            function AddAccount() {
                $("#btnAddAccount").click(function (e) {   

                    var arrayDetail = [];
                    var sArrayDetail = "";

                    $.each($(".acc_table .acc-row"), function (index, value) {
                    //how can I add sequence number? [number of rows] 1,2,3,4...
                    // when looping I want to do a validation here
                    // if user enter debit side, the entry type will be '10',
                    //  if user enter credit side, the entry type will be '20',
                    // user are not able to enter debit and credit side in a row.
                    
            let desc = $(this).find(".row-desc").val()
                        let debit = $(this).find(".row-dr").val()
                        let credit = $(this).find(".row-cr").val()
            let entrytype = 0

                        let detail = {
                            accDescription: desc,
                            accAmount: debit,//how can I define the amount is on debit or credit side?
                            accEntryType: entrytype,//(debit:10, :credit 20), //at there it should give me either 10 or 20 based on where the user key in the amount.
                        }
                        arrayDetail.push(detail)
                    });
                    console.log(arrayDetail)

            sArrayDetail = JSON.stringify(arrayDetail);

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "AddAccount",
                        data: JSON.stringify({sArrayDetail }),
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (result) {

                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response.d);
                        }
                    });
            })
            };
</script>
```

Comment: Hi , what do you mean by `the entry type will be '10' and when user enter at the credit column, the entry type will be '20'..` ?

Comment: it means that in database I have a column AccEntryType, it store '10' or '20' value, because in my database, I set 10 as the debtor and 20 as creditor. So I will know the amount is record under who.

Comment: So when user enter the amount in debit column,  it will define that this amount's entry type is 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When user type in debit or credit input box you can check if the value of either side is not empty depending on this show some message to user . Then , you can use same condition to add *accAmount* and *accEntryType* in your json .

***Demo code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  AddAccount();

  $('#addrow').click(function() {
    addRow();
  });

});

$(document).on('click', '.delete-row', function() {
  $(this).parents('.acc-row').remove();
});

$(document).on('keyup', '.row-dr, .row-cr', function(e) {
  var dr = 0;
  cr = 0;
  total_cr = 0,
    total_dr = 0;
  var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
  //if debit side is not empty and use typing in credit side
  if ($row.find('input.row-dr').val() != "" && $(this).hasClass("row-cr")) {
    $(this).val("") //empty that value
    console.log("sorry you have enter value already at debit side")
  } else if ($row.find('input.row-cr').val() != "" && $(this).hasClass("row-dr")) {
    $(this).val("")
    console.log("sorry you have enter value already at credit side")

  }
  $(".acc-row").each(function() {
    total_dr += $(this).find(".row-dr").val() != "" ? parseFloat($(this).find(".row-dr").val()) : 0
    total_cr += $(this).find(".row-cr").val() != "" ? parseFloat($(this).find(".row-cr").val()) : 0
  })
  $("#debit").val(total_dr.toFixed(2))
  $("#credit").val(total_cr.toFixed(2))

});

function addRow() {
  var addRows =
    '<tr class="acc-row">' +
    '<td><a class="delete-row" href="javascript:; ">Delete</i></a></td>' +
    '<td><input class="form-control tx-right row-accDesc" type="text"></td>' +
    '<td><input class="form-control tx-right row-dr" type="text"></td>' +
    '<td><input class="form-control tx-right row-cr" type="text"></td>' +
    '</tr>'
  $(".acc_table").append(addRows);
}


function AddAccount() {
  $("#btnAddAccount").click(function(e) {

    var arrayDetail = [];
    var sArrayDetail = "";

    $.each($(".acc_table .acc-row"), function(index, value) {
      let desc = $(this).find(".row-accDesc").val()
      //check if dr input is not empty if yes get that amt or ele next
      let accAmount = $(this).find(".row-dr").val() != "" ? $(this).find(".row-dr").val() : $(this).find(".row-cr").val()
      //saem here
      let accEntryType = $(this).find(".row-dr").val() != "" ? 10 : 20
      let detail = {
        seq_no: index + 1, //for seq no
        accDescription: desc,
        accAmount: accAmount,
        accEntryType: accEntryType,
      }
      arrayDetail.push(detail)
    });
    console.log(arrayDetail)

    //your ajax call
  })
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example-input" class="table table-bordered text-nowrap">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="wd-5p"></th>
      <th class=" wd-20p">Description</th>
      <th class="wd-10p tx-right">Debit</th>
      <th class="wd-10p tx-right">Credit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="acc_table">
    <tr class="acc-row">
      <td>
        <a id="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">Delete</i></a></td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control tx-right row-accDesc" type="text"></td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control tx-right row-dr" type="text" value=""></td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control tx-right row-cr" type="text" value=""></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr id="hiderow">
      <td colspan="6" class="tx-center tx-15"><b><a id="addrow" href="javascript:;" title="Add a row"><i class="fe fe-plus-circle"></i>Add a Row</a></b></td>
      <br>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="valign-middle"></td>
      <td class="tx-right">Total</td>
      <td class="tx-right">
        <input class="form-control tx-right" type="text" placeholder="0.00" id="debit" disabled></td>
      <td class="tx-right">
        <input class="form-control tx-right" type="text" placeholder="0.00" id="credit" disabled></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>

<button id="btnAddAccount" type="button">Count </button>
```

Comment: Wow, amazing! I have been struggling of this for 2 weeks. You solved my question in just few hours. Really appreciate your works!!

Comment: Want to ask how to make the validation for the  $("#debit").val() &
  $("#credit").val()?? If the amount enter both side is not tally, it should said not tally before goes ajax. For example my debit is 100 and my credit is 300.

Comment: debit total should be greater then credit total ?

Comment: debit total should be same as credit total

Comment: if user make the total debit and total credit not same, then it should said "the amount for both side is not same, please check it again." Until the both side total is same, then only can go through ajax

Comment: Hi , just add condition `if (parseFloat($("#debit").val()) == parseFloat($("#credit").val()))        { //your ajax code json } else { //show  error message }`